# Can't stop XDEBUG session

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I'm new to xdebug.  Netbeans seems to connect just fine.  Connecting remote to a vm on my local machine.  remote_enable is on and zend_extension is an absolute path to xdebug.  I get my debug information in the browser.  But for some reason I can't get the session to close.  Netbeans will say the session ended successfully however I still get all the traces from xdebug in the browser...
How do I get xdebug to go away when I'm not debugging.  Passing the query string to stop xdebug doesn't change anything.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the traces are only modifiable in your php.ini. Starting or Stopping debugging does not affect the output from traces. If you want to stop the html formatted exception call stacks, see their page: http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace. From quickly reading their site, it seems like you'd have to comment out the xdebug extension from the php.ini file.

Comment: This works.  I just figured there would be a bit more elegant way to do it.